# Tool bar display issue in text-angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using textAngular Directive to implement HTML editor in my application.

I have followed all the steps mentioned in there wiki (In Git repository).

I used bower to installed textAngular.

Folling are my code snippets

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "Appname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "highcharts": "~4.0.4",
    "bootstrap-calendar": "~0.2.4",
    "smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "~2.3.1",
    "angular-datatables": "~0.3.0",
    "components-font-awesome": "~4.3.0",
    "angular-filter": "~0.5.1",
    "datatables-responsive": "~1.0.2",
    "datatables-colvis": "~1.1.1",
    "textAngular": "~1.3.0",
    "angularjs-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.5.2",
    "lodash": "^3.5.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-switch": "0.3.0",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "~1.2.1",
    "ngImgCrop": "~0.3.2",
    "angular-file-upload": "~1.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.0",
    "rangy-core":"~1.2.3",
      "rangy-saveselection":"~1.2.3"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

Index.html

CSS:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngular.css" /
```

Scripts :

```
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-cssclassapplier.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-selectionsaverestore.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-serializer.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngularSetup.js"></script>
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
     <text-angular ng-model="htmlVariable"></text-angular>
 </div>
```

Please help me in finding what I am doing wrong

Regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It my bad,

made mistake in application css

```
.btn-default{
width: 100%;
}
```

tool bar is using btn-defalt class